# C# modifying a list in a function

Tags: c#, list, reference

I am writing a function which is passed in a list which is partially filled.  I'd like to set some of the fields within the list inside this function.  I thought that passing it as a reference would allow me to do this, however, I get the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' because it is not a variable

I am wondering what I might need to do to tell C# that I wish to have the option of modifying the contents of the list.

Here is a summarized version of my code:

```
    public static void Determine_RTMM_Descriptor(ref List<Struct_Descriptor_Type> symbols, string Dwarf_Output_Filename)
    {
        ...
        lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Dwarf_Output_Filename);

        //loop on symbol names
        for (int idx = 0; idx < symbols.Count; idx++)
        {

            if(symbols[idx].size == 0) 
                symbols[idx].size = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString(split_line[DwarfInterface.SIZE_INDEX]);

        ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's passed in by reference by default, no need for ref

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be using a `struct`, and should instead be using a `class`.  The error that you're seeing is just one of the many reasons why mutable structs are evil; that you aren't familiar with it means that you'll most likely do all sorts of other Bad Things that the compiler *can't* catch for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that you have a list of value types.  When you use the indexer of the list to get an item from the list you are getting a *copy* of that type.  The code `symbols[idx]` is the *value* of that item.  It is not a *variable* representing that item, as the error message is telling you.

You're trying to mutate the size of the *copy*, which will have no effect on the item of the list.  This is such a common mistake that the compiler even makes this an error.

If you *really* are sure that you want to have a mutable value type (hint: you aren't, and you shouldn't have one; you almost certainly just want to have a `class` here to avoid this problem entirely) then you would need to get the value of the item, mutate it, and then set the item again:

```
if(symbols[idx].size == 0) 
{
    var symbol = symbols[idx];
    symbol.size = 42;
    symbols[idx] = symbol;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your return type on the function is "void" when you should set the return type to the list.  That should allow you to change it and return it modified.

Comment: 1) There's no need to return the list; he can just mutate the parameter as he's not creating a new list 2) This doesn't address the error message brought up in the question at all.

Comment: I agree, he can just change the parameter, but he can also return the modified list, which I have done many times.  And it certainly does answer his question.  There's no need to down vote my answer, it is an answer!

Comment: What is the point in redundantly returning the mutated list?  It is accomplishing *nothing*, nor is it enabling anything for the caller, as they already have access to the list; they couldn't call the method without it.  And no, your answer isn't an answer to the question; it is not explaining why he's getting the error that he's getting, merely suggesting a change that changes nothing.